# Automatic newline in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, word-wrap

Using jQuery, how can I make a textarea that automatically adds a new line when inserting text when the cursor is near the end.

The width of the textarea is dynamically done via CSS (e.g., `#myTextArea { width: 80%; }`) so I can't do anything like counting the characters in each line.

I don't need a non-JS solution since the content of the textarea is only ever seen by JavaScript anyways.

Comment: This will be difficult; but, just out of curiosity, why do you want this? As you'll probably know textareas wordwrap nicely by default.

Comment: For what exactly you need to do that? Depending on what you want the style `word-wrap:break-word;` can perhaps solve your problem.

Comment: @Marcel - Yes, but in a way that's invisible to the script.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really nasty problem to try and solve.  I'd be going down either 1 of 2 pahts.  1 just use the text area as is or 2 using a nice jQuery editor which makes the text look nice.